# How to recover Orient db data loss

Tags: orientdb

I executed the command

```
  alter databases locallanguage_tr
```

in orientdb and now I cant access my database all the data is gone

Is there a way to recover from this?

Comment: That single command will only print an IllegalArgumentException without even reaching your db, what version of OrientDB are you using? Did you execute other commands?

Comment: My previous answer implies you're running "alter database" without the s.

Comment: hi otherid if you have a backup you can restore the db with "restore database /backups/mydb.zip"

Comment: our team backuped the data from the company providing hosting  thanks